# How to write in etherscan.io "Info" tab with hardhat/truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, etherscan, hardhat

I would like to achieve the same result as the below images.

How could I populate the "Info" tab on etherscan.io with hardhat/truffle ?

**Example 1:**

https://etherscan.io/address/0x42069abfe407c60cf4ae4112bedead391dba1cdb#notes

[image]

**Example 2:**

[image]